# Limit client apps used with ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

We have configured Ejabberd.

I need to find a way to restrict end-users so they can only use the Gaijim XMPP client.

I have researched how to do this on various forums, however I have had no luck.

Does Ejabberd allow restricting client apps used?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any module to limit that.

There's mod_statsdx, which can be configured to query the clients for their software version, but that information is only gathered for showing statistics in WebAdmin.

Anyway, of course, clients could provide incorrect information to be accepted as Gajim clients...

Comment: ok, thanks for the help